# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Products#edit

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I'm having trouble in a sales site, I have a User and produito the protuto User belongs to, everything works right exeto edit the action of the product.

ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Products#edit

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :user_id=>#} missing required keys: [:id]

```
my_edit
    <h1>Editing product</h1>

    <%= render 'form' %>

    <%= link_to 'Show', @product %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>

my _form

    <%= form_for  [:user,@product], :html => {multipart: true} do |f| %>
      <% if @product.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :price %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :price %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :local %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :local %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :description %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
        <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map {|c| [c.name, c.id]} %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :contacts %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :contacts %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :image %><br>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>


my rake routes

 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
     sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                     sessions#new
category_category GET    /categories/:id/category(.:format)          categories#category
       categories GET    /categories(.:format)                       categories#index
                  POST   /categories(.:format)                       categories#create
     new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                   categories#new
    edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)              categories#edit
         category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                   categories#show
                  PATCH  /categories/:id(.:format)                   categories#update
                  PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                   categories#update
                  DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                   categories#destroy
       home_index GET    /home(.:format)                             home#index
                  POST   /home(.:format)                             home#create
         new_home GET    /home/new(.:format)                         home#new
        edit_home GET    /home/:id/edit(.:format)                    home#edit
             home GET    /home/:id(.:format)                         home#show
                  PATCH  /home/:id(.:format)                         home#update
                  PUT    /home/:id(.:format)                         home#update
                  DELETE /home/:id(.:format)                         home#destroy
     profile_user GET    /users/:id/profile(.:format)                users#profile
    user_products GET    /users/:user_id/products(.:format)          products#index
                  POST   /users/:user_id/products(.:format)          products#create
 new_user_product GET    /users/:user_id/products/new(.:format)      products#new
edit_user_product GET    /users/:user_id/products/:id/edit(.:format) products#edit
     user_product GET    /users/:user_id/products/:id(.:format)      products#show
                  PATCH  /users/:user_id/products/:id(.:format)      products#update
                  PUT    /users/:user_id/products/:id(.:format)      products#update
                  DELETE /users/:user_id/products/:id(.:format)      products#destroy
            users GET    /users(.:format)                            users#index
                  POST   /users(.:format)                            users#create
         new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                        users#new
        edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                   users#edit
             user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#show
                  PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                  PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                  DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                        users#destroy
         sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                         sessions#create
            login GET    /login(.:format)                            sessions#new
           logout GET    /logout(.:format)                           sessions#destroy
             root GET    /                                           home#index
```

Comment: can you show your link which takes you to edit page?

Comment: ok     <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_product_path %>

Comment: Post your error backtrace and related controller/form code

Comment: ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Products#edit

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :user_id=>#} missing required keys: [:id] accuses the error this line   <%= form_for  [:user,@product], :html => {multipart: true} do |f| %>

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I found that you are missing to pass ID for the product.

You need to pass `@user` & `@product` objects like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_product_path(@user, @product) %>
```

Comment: isso nao funcionou, o erro apenas muda para este

ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Products#show

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"products", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :user_id=>#<Product id: 1, title: "mac com windows", price: 34233.0, local: "rwfr", description: "4243", category_id: 1, contacts: "fwefwedfs", created_at: "2014-09-12 17:56:10", updated_at: "2014-09-12 17:56:11", image_file_name: "product-6.jpg", image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 6834, image_updated_at: "2014-09-12 17:56:10", user_id: 1>} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Is the error occurring while submitting the form? Check updated answer